# NO INTERNET (wired or or wireless) Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, kernel, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new XPS 15. I am new to Ubuntu/Linux. I went looking for solutions and found that I probably need to update my kernel. (It has something to do with the compatibility with the killer wifi 6 ax500-dbs, I think? My current kernel version is 5.8.0, but I need 5.10.0 I think) BUT, everywhere I have looked, the directions for updating the kernel require, well, internet. Which, I don't have. The Ubuntu installation is not showing either wireless or wired network connection. My Network works fine with other laptops, so there's a network readily available. But with the new Ubuntu install the Network icon just isn't there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try downloading the Specific Network Driver for Linux from `XPS 15` and install it. Use a Thumb drive to transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try to establish internet connection to your laptop is to connect your smartphone (android/iOS) to your laptop via USB cable and activate hotspot which will use your data, but you'll have internet connection on your laptop.

Similarly android phones support "WiFi tethering" via USB cable, which will use WiFi instead your data plan.

These are not direct solutions to your issue, but I hope this helps even a bit.